# Accord.Neuro in .NET: how to retrieve the neural networks weigths from the network?

Tags: neural-network, f#, visual-studio-2019, accord.net

I am trying to make my head around Accord.NET.Neuro. I need a NN library to be used for a reinforcement learning problem. Following one of the examples, I have written this small piece of code in F#:

```
let inputs = [|  [|0.0;1.0|]  ;   [|1.0;1.0|]   |]
let inputdimension = inputs.[0] |> Array.length 
let outputs = [|  [|1.0|]  ;   [|0.0|]   |]
let outputdimension = outputs.[0] |>  Array.length 

let network =  Accord.Neuro.ActivationNetwork (
                SigmoidFunction (2.0) , // transfer function
                inputdimension,
                2 , // two neuron in first layer
                outputdimension ) // one neuron in second layer

let teacher = network |>  LevenbergMarquardtLearning 
teacher.RunEpoch(inputs,outputs)
```

How can I obtain the weights from trained network object? Network does **not** have any weight property, as far as I can tell. Also, in order to make predictions, there is a Compute method; so -after learning- a prediction is made running:

```
network.Compute( [|1.0;1.0|] )
```

for example for a given input. I have noticed that, after several epochs, the network adapts incrementally to the desired targets (as it should be), but -for the training- one just runs

```
teacher.RunEpoch(inputs,outputs)
```

several times. Apparently this affects the network instance: how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weights are accessible through the layers property and then neuron.

So, for the given example,

```
network.Layers
```

provides an array of Layer (Layer[]) where each elements gives information (and data) of each hidden layer. In the example we have input, hidden, and output: so we identify the internal connections: input to hidden and hidden to output.

Suppose we want to know the weights from the input to hidden layer:

```
network.Layers.[0]
```

this line would return a Layer object (Accord.Neuro.Layer) which has a field Neuron.
It is worthwile to look into the interface of these two objects because they represent the neural computations in Accord.Neuro.
Neuro reports the weights of the specific computational unit (and their threshold).

So, a possible helper function to go through the network and get both weights and thresholds would be :

```
let getWeigths (n:ActivationNeuron ) =
    (n.Weights, n.Threshold)

let getNetworkParameters (network:ActivationNetwork) = 
    network.Layers
    |> Array.map ( fun layer -> layer.Neurons  
                                |> Array.map  (fun neuron -> 
                                                    neuron :?> ActivationNeuron 
                                                    |> getWeigths) )
```

I may add some other notes, the more I go through the Accord.Neuro API.